# The location of Solve() function in OpenCV sourcecode

Tags: opencv, svd

Does anyone know where the function bool solve`(mat, mat, result, Decomp_Method)` located in OpenCV sourcecode?

I would like to read the sourcecode of this function, but cant locate it in the sourcecode.

I think it in core module, but cant find it anywhere apart from a dll interface in the core.hpp.

Thanks and best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is located in [modules\core\src\lapack.cpp](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/src/lapack.cpp#L1050)